# Classic ASP form post with sensitive fields

Tags: post, asp-classic, hidden-field

helping my friend with his old ASP site and ran into an issue so I wanted to throw this out to see if i can get some help.

The site basically needs to POST data to another page which it's doing fine. The problem is that it's needs to POST the username/password to the receiving page and the site is currently holding that in hidden fields which is obviously no good since you can see it in the source code.

How can you pull the data in on the ASP page without having it hidden in an input field? I know it can get stored as a variable but then I can't POST it and if I put that variable in an input value field it shows up in the source.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Just in case anyone is interested here's what I ended up doing since I had to use POST to get to the other site. We worked with them to developer a web service that would let us send over all the sensitive data over to it over SSL. In return I would get a one time use token that I would post to the site for them to identify my request and retrieve the values that were passed to them in the earlier web service call. This is working pretty smooth and I feel like it's a fairly secure way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> it needs to POST the username/password to the receiving page

No it doesn't. :)

If the two pages are part of the same site, use the Session object.

If the two pages are on different sites, things are trickier, but the idea is similar. I'm guessing this isn't the case for you, but if it is, look at OAuth. (For example, when you log in here, you use authentication from another site, but stackoverflow never sees your password for that site. Same idea.)

Comment: I wish! Unfortunately they are posting the data over to another external site which is using the POST data to verify/authenticate.

Comment: Oh. So it's YOUR user/pass and you want to hide it from your users? Just make the HTTP request on the server side once you have all the data that you're going to send. There's a standard COM component you can use for that: MSXML.XmlHttpRequest, if I recall correctly.

Comment: Indeed, the most simple component is Microsoft.XMLHTTP (look here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290591)

Answer (score 0):

Create a database table that looks like

```
 uniqueidentifier   SessionId
 varchar            Username
 varchar            Password
```

Store the SessionId in the cookie with `Response.Cookies`.

Get the SessionId from the cookie in JavaScript, and send an ajax request to a page that gets the username and password from the database using the SessionId and outputs the values in JSON.  Attach the values with javascript to a hidden field.  You will still appear to be getting a value from the hidden field on the page that receives the form post, but if  a user views the page source it would just say something like `<input type="hidden" id="username" name="username" value="DefaultUserNameValue" />`.  The value will be assigned dynamically using javascript, which is not visible to the User.

Comment: Is not visible to the user? Wrong. Just use Firebug to peak at the updated source or any tool to peak at the traffic and presto! username and password is yours.

Comment: Yes, it's hackable.  But you can prevent the user from executing this script in an unauthorized manner by sticking to AJAX for the POST and by validating the http request further server-side.  This is not a complete solution but is the foundation for storing sensitive data in a server-side session and providing a mechanism to access that data from the web client.  Also, the post author did not express security concerns to the extent they were worried someone would use Firebug and analyze the javascript, but that they would leave sensitive values in plainly visible places.